# Android - Is it possible to let onItemLongClick trigger itself?

Tags: android

I was trying to let the onItemLongClick to execute itself again. But not show how to do it . i am seeking something like `performItemClick` but for LongClick instead.

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                               int pos, long id) {

                    if (counter == 0) {
                        counter++;
                        // code to let the longclick method to run again
                        return true;
                    }

                     // logic TODO

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure call it recursively:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int pos, long id) {

                if (counter == 0) {
                    counter++;
                    // code to let the longclick method to run again
                    return onItemLongClick(parent, view, position, id);
                }

                 // logic TODO

                return true;
            }
        });
```